# Error al Deserializar Json

Tags: c#

Tengo un json al que quiero deserializar, pero al depurar en c# me da el siguiente error:
"Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidCastException' en Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Información adicional: Al menos un elemento de la matriz de origen no se puede convertir en la matriz de destino."

Aqui es la línea donde da el error:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody, typeof(DataTable));
```

Espero me podais ayudar.
El formato del json es el siguiente:

```
[{
    "orden_id": 191,
    "orden_estado_id": 5,
    "empresa_id": 1,
    "sucursal_id": 1,
    "cliente_id": 5751,
    "cliente_direccion_id": 6240,
    "usuario_id": 1,
    "forma_de_pago_id": 1,
    "orden_creado_por_usuario_id": 1,
    "orden_numero": "OT000001",
    "orden_start_date": "2019-08-19 12:30:00",
    "orden_end_date": "2019-08-19 14:30:00",
    "orden_text": "Prindo S.L.",
    "orden_descripcion_averia": "Se ha roto el grifo de una caldera de la marca Vaillant y hay que cambiarlo ya que no pueden llenar el circuito y el cliente esta sin calefacción.",
    "orden_descripcion_trabajo": "Texto de ejemplo del trabajo realizado por el trabajador",
    "orden_observaciones": "",
    "orden_garantia": "0",
    "orden_guardia": "0",
    "orden_facturado": "1",
    "orden_recibe_firma": "Pedro Rodríguez Font",
    "orden_recibe_dni": "40300000P",
    "orden_fecha_add": "2019-06-20 19:29:24",
    "orden_fecha_upd": "2020-01-28 09:51:01",
    "orden_delete": 0,
    "orden_autorizacion_numero": "5555555555",
    "proyecto_id": 0,
    "presupuesto_id": 0,
    "orden_tipo_id": 0,
    "contrato_id": 0,
    "orden_custom_id": "",
    "ordenes_articulos": [],
    "ordenes_articulos_stock": [],
    "ordenes_checklist": [],
    "ordenes_equipos": [],
    "ordenes_fotos": [],
    "ordenes_operarios": []  
}]
```

Comment: Deberias colocar como estas obteniendo el json para saber si falta algo en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Ramiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes muchos ejemplos como deserealizar json. Pero  siempre lo mas facil es convertir tu objeto en clases y se lo pasas al conversor.

```
var MiObjeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MiClase>(responseBody);

public class MiClase
{
    public int orden_id { get; set; }
    public int orden_estado_id { get; set; }
    public int empresa_id { get; set; }
    public int sucursal_id { get; set; }
    public int cliente_id { get; set; }
    public int cliente_direccion_id { get; set; }
    public int usuario_id { get; set; }
    public int forma_de_pago_id { get; set; }
    public int orden_creado_por_usuario_id { get; set; }
    public string orden_numero { get; set; }
    public string orden_start_date { get; set; }
    public string orden_end_date { get; set; }
    public string orden_text { get; set; }
    public string orden_descripcion_averia { get; set; }
    public string orden_descripcion_trabajo { get; set; }
    public string orden_observaciones { get; set; }
    public string orden_garantia { get; set; }
    public string orden_guardia { get; set; }
    public string orden_facturado { get; set; }
    public string orden_recibe_firma { get; set; }
    public string orden_recibe_dni { get; set; }
    public string orden_fecha_add { get; set; }
    public string orden_fecha_upd { get; set; }
    public int orden_delete { get; set; }
    public string orden_autorizacion_numero { get; set; }
    public int proyecto_id { get; set; }
    public int presupuesto_id { get; set; }
    public int orden_tipo_id { get; set; }
    public int contrato_id { get; set; }
    public string orden_custom_id { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_articulos { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_articulos_stock { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_checklist { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_equipos { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_fotos { get; set; }
    public object[] ordenes_operarios { get; set; }
}
```